# Issue with QGIS 3.28 Traing Manual Exercise 3.3 "Rename Current..."

Tags: qgis, training

I am using QGIS 3.28. I am working on the training manual exercises, using the provided data. I am on exercise 3.3.3 'Follow along: Ration Classification' (see image).
i cannot find "Rename Current..." in the properties dialog.
when i click on "Save Style..." in this dialog, this opens the "Save Layer Style" dialog box, but it has no option to rename (see image).

i tried right-clicking on the layer in the content pane. there i could find an option to "Rename Current" (see image). however, when i tried that route, and continued with the exercise, my AREA field was never updated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The training documentation you are providing is mature and correct in general. You need to get familiar with QGIS interface, thing that comes with spending more time using it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the feature mentioned in the course. It is the same dialog box. Here is what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: awesome, thank you. i came back to it the next day and found this. i think i was having an adhd clerical error (cognitive) issue. anywho, thanks!